# Multi domain SSL shows all the domains publicly

Tags: ssl, storage-area-network

We have generated Multi-domain SSL for my clients but when visiting any client site If we click on the lock icon and navigate to certificate details can see other client domain names in the subject alternative name section. Any suggestions to hide this apart from creating individual certificates?
[SSL Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLCbT.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot hide that, since SAN is part of the certificate, and you need the certificate to be shown to the client. If you don't want the clients to be able to check all the alternate names, you will have to create different certificates.